# What is the difference between the cq:template and cq:templatePath properties in an AEM component?

Tags: aem

Components in AEM 6.0 can have the properties: `cq:template` and `cq:templatePath`. As I am working not both are required always but I don't get the exact difference between these two.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### cq:template

`cq:template` has the type `nt:unstructured`, it allows you to define a complex node with a set of properties and children. It's a node you create as a child of your component definition. This content will be used as default values whenever you drop a new instance of the component from the sidekick.

Here's an example. `componentA` has a child called `cq:template` of the type `nt:unstructured`. The `cq:template` node can have multiple properties and even other nodes as children in case if you need to aggregate some of the properties. Here's how it would look in CRXDE

[image: Use of cq:template]

### cq:templatePath

`cq:templatePath` has the type `String`, it's a simple property, the value of which allows you to point to a node much like one you'd create when using `cq:template`, except it's located elsewhere. Just set it to the path of the node that you want to use as the actual content template definition.

If there's a common pattern in the content used by multiple components, you can define the template in a single place and use `cq:templatePath` to reuse it. If the content is specific to a single component, define it using `cq:template`

Here, `cq:templatePath` is just a property of the node corresponding to the `componentA` component. Its value points to a different node in the repository that contains the actual content to be used as the template. The structure of the other node is the same as in the previous example.

[image: Use of cq:templatePath]

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/components.html)

Comment: i didnt get this- cq:template is of type nt:unstructured. template is of type cq:template. so, how? can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: @theanubhava I didn't say _template is of type cq:template_, I said `cq:template` is `nt:unstructured`, `cq:templatePath` is a `String`. I'll sketch up some example content structures if that helps.

Comment: cq:template is a property of a component, how can it be nt:unstructired. I was asking about this

Comment: It's a child node in the CRX sense. I don't think I call it a property in this answer

Comment: still finding it hard to understand. component cant have any child node of type cq:template?

Comment: The type is `nt:unstructured`, the *name* is `cq:template`

Comment: @theanubhava added some examples with screenshots from CRXDE, hope it's easier to understand now

Comment: Thank you so much @toniedzwiedz ! got it now. Actually, i was looking at cq:template as a property, while it was a child node.